# What is the probability that the Golden State Warriors will break the NBA regular season record of wins?

Tags: probability

There are $82$ games in a regular season, and the current record is held by the Chicago Bulls, at 72-10. As of yesterday (March 4th 2016), the GSW season performance stood at 55-5. Assuming they maintain this record or do better,they need to win at least 18 of their next 22 games.  I calculated the probability of them breaking the Bulls' record as ~7.4%, since each game's outcome is a binomial probability, and the probability of them winning so far is 55/60. I used the following code in R:

```
p = 11/12 #55/60, their current record
q = 1-p
i = c(0:22)
(choose(22,18)*(p^18)*(q^4))/sum(choose(22,i)*(p^i)*(q^(22-i)))
```

But if they keep winning, the probability p of their winning a game will keep changing. How can we take that into consideration while calculating the overall probability?

Comment: "the probability of them winning so far is 55/60" -- perhaps you could use [Laplace's rule of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession)?

Comment: unless I am misreading, your code computes the probability of them losing EXACTLY $4$ of the next $22$ games.  That's not what you intended...you wanted the probability of AT MOST $4$.  Thus you need terms corresponding to $3$ losses, $2$ losses, $1$ loss, and no losses.

Comment: Probability should be used to express/measure randomness. In the outcomes of the games of the GSW there is no randomness (at most little randomness), so using probabilities makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.                                                  lulu: you are absolutely correct, an error on my part. Changing the code accordingly gives me a probability of  0.96,which is more in keeping with the current situation.                               @JimmyR: your comment is valid, and maybe I'm not expressing myself all that well,  but over 22 games, there are a possible 2 raised to 22 outcomes, or of which i want to know the possibility of just one, or a handful. Since the probability of each of those events occurring is equal, doesn't that make it a random event?

Comment: You can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution for modeling.